Parsing 今日まで撮影予備日でスケジュール確保されてたから
I have bit trouble making sense of the structure of this sentence:

今日まで撮影予備日でスケジュール確保されてたから。 (source: Oshi no ko ch. 148)

I believe it can be parsed as follows:

(今日までが撮影予備日)でスケジュールが確保されてたから。
The schedule is filled with movie filming catch-up days (撮影予備日) which lasts until today.

Is that correct? I have doubts on whether で marks means of action or it is just a conjunctive form for だ.

Correct, your parsing is right. Also で is 連用形 of だ in this case.

Also please check this answer about omitting particles.

This question seems more interesting than it looks and deserves more attention from experienced users. I would add another bounty but for now, a question can only have one active bounty

This で can be interpreted in two ways:

As a particle marking a condition. The entire sentence is one clause.

今日まで撮影予備日[で]{as}スケジュール確保されてたから。
≈ スケジュールが撮影予備日として今日まで確保されてたから。
(It's) because the schedule has been secured up until today as backup filming days.
(今日まで is an adverb that modifies 確保する)

Similar use of で would include 大盛りで注文する, VIP席で予約する, 急ぎで進行する, and 別々で計算する.

As the te-form of だ. The sentence is a compound sentence, i.e., two independent clauses joined with a te-form working as "and".

今日まで撮影予備日[で]{and}スケジュール確保されてたから。
≈ 今日までは撮影予備日であって、スケジュールが確保されてたから。
(It's) because the past few days were backup filming days, and so the schedule has been secured.
(今日まで is the subject of 撮影予定日だ)



In this case, both interpretations are possible, and there is no strong reason to reject one of them. FWIW, my initial intuition was the former; I took it as a particle, like @Yuu did. If there was a comma after で, the latter interpretation would be more likely. Besides, if you can listen instead of reading, it's relatively easy to distinguish them by whether there is a short pause after で.
As for スケジュール確保される, it's possible to think of this as a long compound suru-verb similar to 飲酒運転する, but in this case, you can simply think が has been omitted because it's a colloquial sentence.

I'm inclined to feel there are more possibilities in parsing, none of which differs significantly in terms of the meaning. However I am unsure about the grammatical interpretations and would very much like to hear from other members of the site.

First: スケジュール確保する part. As @Gui Imamura points out in the comment, this kind of omission of particles are common and natural, just as in ご飯食べる.
However, "スケジュール確保" as a compound noun, rather than "スケジュールの確保", is not uncommon even outside of casual language (google search) For example:

「スケジュール確保が容易」 --- in 遠隔教育システム活用ガイドブック第3版, by 文部科学省, in reference to a possible advantage of using online learning systems


NHK: 「…は、ゲストのスケジュール確保と予算の制約から、数本分をまとめ撮りしている」 https://www.nhk.or.jp/pr/keiei/bansin/pdf/2013/chugoku2013.pdf

Therefore I think interpretation of "スケジュール確保-する" as a する-verb can safely be justified.  Either way, the sentence in question does not sound overly casual, colloquial, or jargonic.

Second: 「で」
I think it can be understood either as:

で as 連用形 of 助動詞 だ, 「今日までが撮影予備日だ．」 Being 予備日, the schedule was secured
で as 格助詞: デジタル大辞泉 #6 「動作・作用の手段・方法・材料などを表す」 or #7, 「動作・作用の原因・理由を表す」．Like, 「アルバイトで予定を埋める (probably #6)」，「仕事で忙しい (#7) 」，… 「予備日でスケジュールを確保する」, The schedule is filled with (or, secured as) 予備日


Third: the structure
Your interpretation

(今日までが撮影予備日)でスケジュールが確保されてたから。
The schedule is filled with movie filming catch-up days (撮影予備日) which lasts until today.

does seem correct and there's nothing wrong with it. The character could have said: 「今日まで撮影予備日だったんだ．だからスケジュールが確保されてた．」
However, the main point is that they can use that day freely after finishing the filming; that "the schedule has been secured up to today". So if we think of that as the basic structure, it can just as naturally rephrased to

撮影予備日で今日までスケジュールが確保されてたから． The schedule has been secured until today('s schedule) as 撮影予備日.

Which would suggest the structure, {(今日まで) + (撮影予備日で)} (スケジュール確保されてたから) and also で as 格助詞 (if I am not mistaken)．

I am not certain which is correct nor, either I am lacking precision or there is fundamental ambiguity.  If there were punctuation like

今日まで撮影予備日で 、 スケジュール確保されてたから。

, then your interpretation is definitely right. On the other hand, when I read the script, my brain regarded the "今日までスケジュール確保されてた" as the main point.

I think the word で has the same usage as the word で in: ハサミで, 車で (Describe the tools, methods, and means to carry out the action)
The schedule was secured with a contingency/backup day of filming until today.

This で is the 連用形 of the だ auxiliary verb and the sentence can be rewriten as: 今日までが撮影予備日であり、〜
